# How can I make the splash screen on a React-Native Expo app ADA compliant?

Tags: react-native, expo, google-play, accessibility

I am releasing an Expo app in the Google Play Store, and my Pre-launch report is rendering an accessibility error for my Splash Screen.

The error says: `This item may not have a label readable by screen readers.`

How do I add an accessibility label to the Splash Screen? The Splash Screen renders from the `splash` object in the `app.json` file. Here is an example:

```js
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/logos/logo.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#000000"
    },
```

I looked for documentation about Expo Splash Screen Parameters, but I have not found any that were ADA specific.

Will I have to customize my own Splash Screen, and not use Expo's default screen, in order to make it accessible?

Comment: Do you have an image in your splash screen?  If so, does it have alternative text?  See if this helps - https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/7158690

Comment: Expo generates its splash screen from the splash object in the app.json file. I am unable to add `android:contentDescription` to this object. I am starting to think that I will have to build a custom Splash Screen in order to add accessibility. I was hoping for a more simple solution.